# How do I create separate template HTML files using Meteor Iron Router

Tags: javascript, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

I have three folders

> client
>
> router
>
> server

In the **client** folder there is another folder called **views** which contain a file called **layout.html**, **home.html**, and **login.html**.

In **router** folder there is a router.js file with

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: "Layout"
});

Router.route( "/", function(){
  this.render( "Home" );
});

Router.route( "/login", function(){
  this.render( "Login" );
});
```

In the **layout.html** file I have

```
<template name="Layout">
  <h1>Hello Layout</h1>
  {{ > yield }}
</template>
```

> **hello Layout** renders just fine, but the home template is not found.

If I include all templates in the **layout.html** then routing works 4.0.

How do I manage the routes correctly so that each template can remain in its own file?

**UPDATE**
Here are the other respective templates

```
<template name="Home">
  <h1>This Is Home</h1>
</template>

and

<template name="Login">
  <h1>This Is Login</h1>
</template>
```

**UPDATE 2**

I am also trying to use meteor-angular, which wants html files to be name.ng.html.

Removing the **ng** from the file name so that it matched what I described above, and it all works again. I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into this.

Comment: Can you share the home template?

Comment: Ah, I forgot that the file names were home.ng.html as I am also trying to use meteor-angular. removing the ng and the routes work.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem a few days ago.

If you are using Meteor version 1.2, probably it is not working due to the following problem:

https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-middleware-stack/pull/7

You can confirm it by checking if you are getting an exception like :

```
Exception in callback of async function: ReferenceError: EJSON is not defined
```

So while they don't update the package to fix it, add the 'ejson' package:

```
meteor add ejson
```

After it, it should work.